# Input for function

Tags: python, function, if-statement, input

Im trying to code in python a function that reacts to a input

example

```
Action = input("Input:")
function commands():
       if action == Commands:
         print("Commands so far")
```

but I don't know how to get the function to work.
any help?

Comment: in python you use `def` keyword to define functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
def react(action):
    if action == 'act':
        print('act given')
inp = input("Type action: ")
react(inp)
```